# how to parse json array into listview

Tags: android, json

friends i am trying to put json data into a list view but i am not getting it, i am fetching the data from json it is displaying in log cat please help me in this.

```
                JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(data);

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Actors actor = new Actors();


                    JSONObject author = object.getJSONObject("author");
                     String authorName = author.getString("name");
                     Log.d("All Products: ", authorName.toString());
                     String avatar = author.getString("avatar");
                     Log.d("All Products: ", avatar.toString());

                     JSONArray author1 = object.getJSONArray("bm_property_owner_email");
                     // new code embedded
                    //actor.setAuthor(jRealObject.getString("bm_property_owner_email"));
                    //actorsList.add(actor);
                     Log.d("bm_property_owner_email: ", author1.toString());

                      JSONObject links = object.getJSONObject("meta").getJSONObject("links");
                       String collectionLink = links.getString("collection");
                      Log.d("Content: ", collectionLink.toString());
```

Comment: where is your listview code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your JSONArray into a "custom adapter" where in the getView function you can create your list row view.

You can even create a list of Java objects and pass that to your custom adapter.

There are enough examples on the internet to help you create the custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
String id = response.getString("ID");
String title = response.getString("title");

JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("author");
Actors actor = new Actors();
actot.setID(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString(
                                            "ID"));
actor.setUserName(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString(
                                            "username"));
actor.setName(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString(
                                            "name"));
JSONArray insideJsonArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0)                                                      .getJSONArray("meta");
for (int i = 0; i < insideJsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("links");
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++) {
      JSONObject jObject = array.getJSONObject(j);
      String self = jObject.getString("self");
      String archives = jObject.getString("archives");
    }        
}
```

Comment: yar my json is JSONArray without object name. i cant do like this, this works for JSONObject with object name. i dont have object name i have a json link directly going to jsonarray

Comment: Upload your json array.

Comment: JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(data);
for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
JSONObject author = object.getJSONObject("author");
String authorName = author.getString("name");
Log.d("All Products: ", authorName.toString());
String avatar = author.getString("avatar");
JSONArray author1 = object.getJSONArray("bm_property_owner_email");
JSONObject links = object.getJSONObject("meta").getJSONObject("links");
String collectionLink = links.getString("collection");
} like this i am fetching data from jsonarray. now tell me how to call in list view